# AMD GPU for a workstation

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop

I am assembling a new workstation and don't know what kind of GPU I need.

I am thinking about an AMD GPU since I need OpenCL 2.x, but there are quite a lot of options:

- Radeon Pro WX 9100
- Radeon RX Vega 64
- Radeon Pro Frontier Edition
- AMD FirePro W9100

and I don't really understand what GPU to choose. All of them are more or less the same.

The purpose of the workstation is to run heterogeneous physics computations.

Could you please advise me which GPU is better to take for my purposes.

Additional information: I don't know if it plays a role in the decision making, but I am planning to put two GPUs in the workstation.

Comment: "heterogeneous physics computations" Can you be more specific? What application? Are you programming GPU yourself?

Comment: Also fair warning: Vega GPU prices are *super* inflated right now thanks to mining.

Comment: I am using OpenCL for solving problems of fluid mechanics, heat equations,... (PDEs in one word), N-body simulations, rendering using path tracing on GPU.

Comment: What applications are you using? Are you writing this yourself?

Comment: I am writing it myself

Comment: Why two GPUs? Are the calculations really that intensive? What is your budget?